# Presenter name error uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've started implementing presenters for some of my complex views using the following RailsCast as a guide: http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch

I'm getting the following error `NameError at /bids/41 uninitialized constant BidPresenter` and can not figure out where I am going wrong! Better Errors tells me it's this line causing the error in the helper: `klass ||= "#{object.class}Presenter".constantize`

```
# presenter helper
# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWN1nUlgQ8Y
def present(object, klass = nil)
  # if a klass isn't specified determine the class based off the object 
  # klass (bids presenter, user presenter etc)
  klass ||= "#{object.class}Presenter".constantize
  # instantiate presenter
  presenter = klass.new(object, self)
  # yield presenter if a block is given
  yield presenter if block_given?
  # return presenter back from the method
  presenter
end
```

My `bids_presenter.rb`:

```
class BidsPresenter
    def initialize(bid, template)
        @bid = bid
        @template = template
    end

    # h method returns the template object
    def h
        @template
    end

    def bid_data_upper_price_estimate
        h.number_to_currency(@bid.upper_price_estimate, precision: 2)
    end
end
```

My view `show.html.erb`:

```
<% present @bid do |bid_presenter| %>
    <%= bid_presenter.bid_data_upper_price_estimate %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is called `BidsPresenter`, but your error says the code is looking for `BidPresenter`.

No "s".